# Why OnlyOffice throws Error 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, centos7, onlyoffice

Error accessing OnlyOffice

http://192.168.100.22:8080/
Main screen is: Please do not reload the page or shut down your computer.

When inspecting the page I see the error:
https://192.168.100.22:8080/api/2.0/capabilities.json - 502 Bad Gateway

CentOS 7 installation

```
wget https://download.onlyoffice.com/install/groups-install.sh
sudo bash groups-install.sh

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?